# Set min X, max X, min Y, max Y for a Canvas in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

In Android Studio, I created a canvas. Width = 300dp, Height = 300dp.

I draw a line start from left top corner and end to right bottom corner. I traced the x and y coordinates. It is from (0, 0) in left top corner and to (1000+, 1000+) in right bottom corner.

But,

How to set (0,0) in left top corner and (300,300) in right bottom corner?

Comment: You should show some code however its probably the coordinates you are tracing out is the pixels and not the dp.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Thank you for response. 
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-drawing-canvas/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/minipaint/MyCanvasView.kt
I am using this code. Here I am tracing x and y coordinates as currentX, currentY variable values.